# condensing a loop and output into one statement

Tags: python

I started out with a simple example to compare Python code to c#, my more usual language:

```
s=''
for x in range(20,1,-3):
    print(x)
    s+="%d%s" % (x,":")
print(s[:-1])
```

to simply output: 20:17:14:11:8:5:2

then I thought about the shortest, not necessarily the most efficient way of doing it and came up with this after reading about list comprehension.

```
print(''.join([("%d%s" % (x,":")) for x in range(20,1,-3)])[:-1])
```

Is there an even shorter way? I know it's a trivial issue, but really it's about learning about all the features of Python and how it differs from other languages.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative (Python 3.6+ only):

```
print(':'.join(f'{i}' for i in range(20, 1, -3)))
```

As already stated though, your aim shouldn't be to make your code as concise as possible. Readability is more important.

Comment: Thanks, I started learning 3.4, didn't know about f. But I don't know how the for loop is working inside the join, I'm only used to list comprehension?

Comment: I still find myself using `'{}'.format(i)` instead out of habit, but thought this was a good place to mention the newer `f'{i}'` syntax since you specifically mentioned learning about all features of the Python language, and this is quite a new one.

Comment: The for in this case is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), which works just like a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) but produces a generator (a kind of iterator) instead of building a list.

Comment: While I like f-strings, I think `str(i)` is a lot clearer here.

Comment: Fair comment, there are certainly better uses for f-strings than this.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
>>> ":".join(map(str, range(20,1,-3)))
>>> '20:17:14:11:8:5:2'
```

Comment: you even *golfed-out* the spaces xD

Comment: golfed-out? is this some kind of meta language for Python developers :)

Comment: It's a reference to code golf, in which the goal is to solve some function with as short a program as possible.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the final slice is just to remove an unused `:`, so how about:

```
print(':'.join(map(str, range(20, 1, -3))))
```

Python is generally not about compactness but readability.

Comment: The most annoying change in Python 3, imho, is when they moved `reduce` from [built in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).